# MVC Routes for an multi tenant application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a MVC application and can't quite get the routing working for my multi-tenant application.  Here is the problem:

I have 2 types of pages in my application, most require the tenant name to be in the url but some don't. e.g.

These Do (tenant name is these examples is samsung and apple):

http://www.mytestapp.com/samsung/customers/add

http://www.mytestapp.com/apple/customers/add

These Don't:

http://www.mytestapp.com/home/register/

http://www.mytestapp.com/home/aboutus/

What routes do i require to get this working? I have tried this but it does not work for the register and about us page.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TenantRoute",
            url: "{tenantid}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { tenantid = "tenantname", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll need a second route to match the non-tenant routes. The default one should match if `register` and `aboutus` are controllers with an `Index` action:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Register", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            "samsung",
            "samsung/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "apple",
            "apple/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Register", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```